# How do I fix this leak in my glass shower surround?

Tags: drywall, shower, leak, caulking, glass

Since we purchased this home in April, we have had issues with a small leak in the glass shower surround, and honestly from looks of it this has been a long persistent issue.

We replaced the door sweep originally, but leak persists.

The old owner caulked over weep holes so I took caulk off of them and redid entire shower caulk focusing on areas near wall where leak is. I thought weep holes now being uncovered would alleviate issue but it’s back again.

I redid the drywall thinking issue was fixed but as photos reveal, small leak continues to win. There is no evidence on ceiling below of leak and it seems to be something with frame.

What do I do to fix this leak?

[image]

Comment: Assuming that the leak is coming from the mesh area just above the finger and the amount of sealant in the corner between the wall and the shower door, AND the joint is sealed between the base and the wall on the inside of the stall,  I'm betting that the leak is coming through the shower door frame and seeping through a gap between the base and the wall behind the door frame.

Comment: This would be prime suspect, but we can't see enough of anything else to even guess - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaARB.jpg

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have noticed when I take all the sealant off that corner, water pools up. I am betting you’re right and water is still seeping through. What would be the best way to fix this? Besides a ton of silicone cause that’s not working.

Comment: Seal the entire joint where the arrow points. For any more we need to be able to see more. Where you've currently sealed, you're after the leak, rather than before it.